# Team City 6.5.5 - MSBuild issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, teamcity

Trying to configure Visual Studio 2008 project (TFS2010) on TeamCity, created build step with MS build selecting 2.0 as the .NET Framework version - but getting the follwoing error:

> **error MSB5014:** File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I also tried selecting Visual Studio (sln) as Runner Type even that is not working.

Comment: Which version of MSBuild ToolsVersion you have selected in TeamCity?

Comment: I have selected .net 2.0 and msbuild tool version 2.0 - then i got the above error, also tried selecting 3.5 for each of them, now it sayd install vs2008,sdk3.5 on the server

Answer (score 5):

Use newer version of MSBuild. See [this link](http://www.csharp411.com/solution-file-error-msb5014/) for more details.

Comment: Did you read the link? You said that you are using MSBuild for .NET Framework 2.0. So, my answer suggests you to use MSBuild for .NET Framework 3.5 or higher.